# prestashop add product size - php

Tags: php, mysql, xml, prestashop

How can I insert product size from XML to MySQL?
Is there any function in prestashop? I wastrying to use addProductAttribute but it's deprecated.
Maybe generateMultipleCombinations ? I hope you can help me.

Here's my code:

```
function query_attribute($xmlNode, $attr_name, $attr_value) {
  foreach($xmlNode as $node) { 
    switch($node[$attr_name]) {
      case $attr_value:
        return $node;
    }
  }
}

include dirname(__FILE__) . '/../config/config.inc.php';
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/../init.php';

ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

$xmlstr = file_get_contents('......xml');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

foreach($xml->products->product as $p)
{

    $desc = (!empty($p->description))?strip_tags($p->description):'...';
    $catid = intval($p->category_id);
    $kateg = $kategorie[$catid];

    $product = new Product();
    $product->ean13 = $p['product_id'];
    $product->name = array((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') => $p->name);
    $product->link_rewrite = array((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') => $p['product_id']);
    $product->description = array((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') => $desc);
    $product->id_category = $kateg;
    $product->id_category_default = $kateg;
    $product->redirect_type = '404';
    $product->price = $p->price_netto;
    //$product->quantity = 1;
    $product->minimal_quantity = 1;
    $product->show_price = 1;
    $product->on_sale = 1;
    $product->online_only = 1;
    $product->meta_keywords = '';
    $product->is_virtual=0;
    $product->manufacturer_name=$p->producer;
    $product->add();

    StockAvailable::setQuantity($p['product_id'], 0, (int) 1);

    $product->addToCategories(array($kateg));

        $default = 1;
        foreach ($p->sizes->size as $size) {

                $quantity = $size['count']; 
                Db::getInstance()->execute("INSERT INTO `ps_attribute_impact` (`id_attribute_impact`, `id_product`, `id_attribute`, `weight`, `price`) VALUES (NULL, '{$product->id}', '{$rozmiary[$size['name']]}', '0', '0');", false);
                //$combinationID = $product->addAttribute($p->price_netto, 0,           1,              0,          $quantity,  'aa',           '',     $default);
                                 //addAttribute($price,     $weight,    $unit_impact,   $ecotax,    $id_images, $reference, $ean13, $default, $location = null, $upc = null, $minimal_quantity = 1, array $id_shop_list = array(), $available_date = null)



                $default = 0;

        }
```

in my XML it looks like:

```
<sizes>
    <size name="S" count="4" />
    <size name="M" count="1" />
    <size name="L" count="4" />
</sizes>
```